# How to add video watermarking in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, instagram, instagram-api

I am making an app of Instagram repost. It works with instagram API and when I try to share from Instagram to my app, it should add watermark in videos.

If any one have tried something like this before, please share your code or any link used here.

Thanks in Advance!